# Javamelody collect server aggregate files

Tags: monitoring, tomcat9, java-melody

I have Javamelody collector war installed on tomcat 9 server.

I am trying to delete added server, but i can't achieve this i have this error:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [32] was present in the Cookie value
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateCookieValue(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:182)
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:115)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:974)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:926)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:385)
net.bull.javamelody.internal.web.HttpCookieManager.addCookie(HttpCookieManager.java:90)
net.bull.javamelody.internal.web.CollectorController.getApplication(CollectorController.java:600)
net.bull.javamelody.CollectorServlet.doGet(CollectorServlet.java:89)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I tried to delete it direclty on file server but i don't fount where those files are located.

[image]

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Response from evernote, there is a bug in current collector javamelody server, server not supported blank space in server name while adding on aggregate server.

hope could help !

Comment: on github master snapshot branch, issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

I personally had a similar issue where I wanted to get ride of a collected monitoring.
I end up editing the applications.properties file on the **collect server**.

```
vi /opt/tomcat/temp/javamelody/applications.properties
```

You will be able to see the list of monitored application

```
#urls of the applications to monitor
#Wed Nov 07 12:08:01 GMT 2018
YouApplication\ serverA=http\://serverB\:8080/YouApplication
```

Then after removing the YouApplication line and restarting the servers it was all good.

Hope it will help.